# Playing an audio until button is pressed in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make button of Harmonium in Android which produces sound when Button is pressed. When button is released, Sound stops. My code is as follow.

```
package com.example.akshay.soundapp;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound);

        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    mp.start();
                }
                else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    mp.stop();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For onTouch(), if I keep true as return value, then button is not appearing to be pressed but produce sound 1 time only. Next time I press, it doesn't work.

If I keep false as return value, button appears as it being pressed and produces sound and sound get stops at release event. But if I try to press button one more time, it doesn't produce sound.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pause() instead of stop() and then return true would work later. Also you should use setLooping(true) if you want audio never stop until you stop touching button.

```
      btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            }
            else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                mp.pause();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: My sound clip has duration of 10 seconds. I pressed button for 11 seconds and released. Again I pressed same button but it doesn't produce sound. What to do?

Comment: I dont know why it's not working for you but this code is correct and it should work perfectly.